# HTML5 cartoon creation

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I want to create a simple short cartoon. Something with characters drawn with sticks and moving sprites. Not a serious project, just a small animated postcard.

I want to write script like this (pseudocode):

```
function train_arriwes_to_the_platform() {
    while(train.x > 0) {
        train.x -= train.speed;
        delay(1000 / FPS);
        redraw();
    };
}

/// other functions

function scene1() {
    clouds_fly_in_the_sky();
    train_arriwes_to_the_platform();
    doors_of_train_opens();
    man_comes_out_of_the_train();
    man_walks_from_the_platform();
}
```

The problem is - javascript is asynchronous, so I need some additional libs to write it like that (promises?) and I have little experience with animation in canvas or SVG. So I need some hits about where to start, or may be some tutorials...

Comment: I think tweenJS might be your friend here. A demo : http://www.createjs.com/#!/TweenJS/demos/tweenSample

Comment: You might want to try Adobe Edge or Tumult Hype or Sencha Animator (my company's product)

Comment: @VincentPiel very nice plugin thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SMIL animation does a perfect job for tasks like this.  Here is a [little example of the described scene](http://jsbin.com/etupuk/1), animated using SMIL, requiring very little animation code:

```
<svg width="400px" height="300px" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="www://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <!-- Sky -->
  <rect width="100%" height="150" fill="#ddf"/>

  <!-- Clouds -->
  <g>
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML"
                    type="translate" from="0" to="500" dur="30s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <g style="fill:#eee" opacity=".8" id="cloud">
      <circle r="40" cx="20" cy="20"/>
      <circle r="35" cx="55" cy="40"/>
      <circle r="33" cx="80" cy="20"/>
    </g>
    <use xlink:href="#cloud" x="250" y="25"/>
    <use xlink:href="#cloud" x="-250" y="25"/>
    <use xlink:href="#cloud" x="-500" y="0"/>
  </g>

  <!-- Landscape -->
  <path d="M0 300
            0 140
           C100 120 120 100 180 130
           S250 120 300 120
           L 400 150
           400 300" fill="#4a3"/>

  <!-- Man -->
  <g transform="translate(280,270) scale(1,-1)">
    <path stroke="#000" fill="none">
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML"
                      type="translate" values="0;-100" dur="6s"
        begin="5s" fill="freeze"/>
        <animate attributeName="d" begin="5s" dur="0.3s" repeatCount="indefinite"
          values="M-3,0 0,10 3,0 M0,10 0,16 l 4,-5 M0,16 l-4,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0;
                  M 0,0 0,10 0,0 M0,10 0,16 l 0,-5 M0,16 l 0,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0;
                  M-3,0 0,10 3,0 M0,10 0,16 l 4,-5 M0,16 l-4,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0"/>
    </path>
  </g>

  <!-- Station -->
  <g>
    <rect width="90" height="40" x="120" y="230" fill="#dd7"/>
    <rect width="100" height="14" x="115" y="220" fill="#a22"/>
    <path stroke-width="18" d="m130 250 h70" stroke="#aac" stroke-dasharray="20 8"/>
  </g>
  <!-- Platform -->
  <rect width="250" height="15" x="70" y="270" fill="#eec"/>

  <!-- tracks -->
  <g color="#aaa">
    <path d="M0 285h400" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="5" id="track"/>
    <use xlink:href="#track" y="3" stroke-dasharray="4 5" color="#411"/>
  </g>

  <!-- train -->
  <g color="#50f" stroke-dasharray="10 70">
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML"
                    type="translate" values="300;200;100;50;0" dur="3s"/>
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML"
                    type="translate" values="0;-100;-200;-350" dur="3s"
      begin="5s" fill="freeze"/>
    <!-- couplings -->
    <path d="M100 273h200" stroke="#000" stroke-dasharray="0" stroke-width="2"/>
    <g id="coach">
      <!-- wheels -->
      <path d="M20 278h100" 
        stroke="#ccc" stroke-width="10" stroke-linecap="round"
        stroke-dasharray="0.001 15 0.001 40"/>
      <!-- body -->
      <rect width="100" height="35" fill="currentColor" x="5" y="240"/>
      <!-- windows -->
      <path d="M10 254h90" stroke-width="10" stroke="#eef"/>
    </g>
    <use xlink:href="#coach" color="#c22" x="105" stroke-dasharray="15 4"/>
    <use xlink:href="#coach" color="#c22" x="210" stroke-dasharray="15 4"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

You can animate graphics that you created with a vector graphics editor by adding the SMIL elements later, but hand coded graphics (like the simplistic ones in this example) are much cleaner and easier to animate.  When using a graphics editor, make sure you group elements in a sensible way. For more complex graphics, you might want to find a good mix between hand coding and incorporating pieces that you created in a graphics editor.

For hand coding, [Tinkerbin](http://tinkerbin.com/) and [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) are nice tools to use because they show you the graphics while you're coding.

You can look up the available SMIL functionality in the [SVG specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html). [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL) might offer a better introduction, but this introduction is not exhaustive.

Be aware that SMIL works basically everywhere except for IE. As a workaround, you can give [FakeSmile](http://leunen.me/fakesmile/) a try, which supports a subset of SMIL.

Comment: Wow, that looks impressive!

Could you tell me more about what tools you used, and where you learned SMIL? SVGEdit with following source editing?

Comment: All of these very simplistic graphics are coded by hand. [Tinkerbin](http://tinkerbin.com) and [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com) show you the graphics while you're coding, I like that a lot. I'm looking up the available SMIL functionality in the [SVG specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html). [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL) might offer a better introduction, but this introduction is not exhaustive. Be aware that SMIL works basically everywhere except for IE. BTW: Thanks for the inspiration! This gave me some relaxing minutes doing fun stuff.

Comment: I added the above comments to the answer, adding some more details.

Comment: Ok, I still have no time to implement my idea, but I think i will do it in your way, so I accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could have an array of functions, each doing one animation step.

You can do timing using `setTimeout` after each step of the animation, or if all steps are the same long, `setInterval` could work too.

You can use **jQuery's animation** functions, it will make it really easy and smooth.

In the example below, some basic ones are shown, but you can animate almost anything with jQuery.

---

Here's some small demonstration code of what I have in mind:

```
// array of animation steps and their lengths
var anim = [
    {
        time: 1000,
        func: function() {
            // do something
            $('#thingOne').fadeIn(1000);
        }
    },
    {
        time: 500,
        func: function() {
            // do something
            // this will span longer than the frame - no problem
            $('#thingOne').fadeOut(1000);
            $('#thingTwo').animate({
                    top: "+=200px",
                }, 500 );
        }
    },
    {
        time: 4000, // long frame
        func: function() {
            // do something
            $('#thingTwo').fadeOut(4000);
        }
    }
];

var stepId = 0;

function animStep() {
    if(stepId < anim.length) {

        var step = anim[stepId];

        step.func();

        stepId++;
        setTimeout(animStep, step.time);
    }
}


// launch the animation
$(document).ready(function(){

    animStep();

});
```

Comment: You _can_ do animation timing with `setTimeout`, but you shouldn't.  You should use `window.requestAnimationFrame` instead.

Comment: @Alnitak that may be good if you wanted to do the animation yourself. I suggested to use jQuery animation, so no animation that would need repaint is actually taking place in my `animFrame()` - it's just a place where I tell jQuery what to do next. I don't think `requestAnimationFrame()` is at all suitable for this purpose.

Comment: It's more suitable than `setTimeout` for each frame, which the start of your answer recommends.

Comment: You probably didn't understand what I am doing. This is about sequencing functions, and there is - in the example, 1s, 0.5s and 4s delay between the calls. I see no benefit in getting animationFrame updates every redraw, only to have to check if the right time has come to start another part of the animation. It seems utterly pointless.

Comment: I understand perfectly well what your code does.  However, before that code, you said _"You can do timing using `setTimeout` after each frame"_.  I'm just pointing out that per-frame timing is best done with `window.requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: Probably not quite *perfectly*, as I do not do per-frame timing at all. Now I replaced all occurences of the word "frame" with "step", if it makes you happy.

Comment: No, I did indeed understand perfectly.  Your use of "step" instead makes your answer much clearer.

Comment: Yes, step or scene is a better term for that functions in array. And thank you for nice idea about how that sequence can be done. I will explore some variants proposed by other users, and accept yours if I will use yours.